# How to stop Visual Studio from formatting whitespace on 'save'?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

This question ([How to disable all whitespace autoformatting in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229830/how-to-disable-all-whitespace-autoformatting-in-visual-studio-2015)) shows different formatting options when writing in a language - for example C#. But it doesn't cover the problem of *everytime I save a file all whitespace is stripped*.

This is INCREDIBLY irritating since I can't go into a file an edit just a line of it and commit. I get merge conflicts everytime there is an extra space anywhere in the file.

I don't want VS 2015 to change white space when I save a file. I do want VS to format my code for me...

Comment: Are you whitespacing by space literal or by TAB? You need to set TAB to "Insert Spaces" otherwise, or they will be purged on the format pass

Comment: Thanks. I found that setting, but it doesn't stop VS stripping unneeded white space on save. For example there is a line with 11 spaces at the end of it. When I save, there are 0 spaces at the end of it. This then gets seen as a change in git, and if someone edited that line in addition to me there is a merge conflict.

Comment: I am using VS2015. The other dev in this case is using VS2013

Comment: I don't know if this would be comprehensive, but two format settings that will preserve a subset of intentional space padding are:
In Tools->Options->TextEditor->C#->Formatting->Spacing:      

Ignore Spaces in Declaration Statements- check this;
Ignore spaces around binary operators- click this radio button(towards bottom);

Comment: @schulmaster that didn't work. the only solution that seemed to work was upgrading to 2017 - also I should mention that I was using bootcamp on a mac previously and I'm not now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade to 2017. The default configuration does what I want. I was not able to get this to work with 2015.

Also I should mention that I was previously running Windows 10 on a mac via Bootcamp and now I'm not. It really shouldn't have mattered but who knows...